# x:Static value in Control does not update

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, default-value

I would love to understand a special part about WPF. I am setting a GridLength (width) value for a ColumnDefinition inside a Control. The value is referencing a static Property of a static class. Of course it does not support INotifyPropertyChanged but all I want is to update the value and when the next instance of this Control gets created it should take the new value. But it doesn't work this way.

I experienced the same behaviour when binding to a dependency property that gets its default value via a static Property. This is never evaluated again and that is logical to me. But just using a field should be ok when creating the next instance.

One thing I just realize while writing this. I am talking about a custom control and  the value is used within a Template. So I am assuming that the ElementFactory gets created using that value and then just pushes out little controls with its internal values. Can somebody confirm that?

If that's how it works, what would be a workaround or better: the correct way to handle this? I am applying a new value to a control-resource in OnApplyTemplate currently.

Thanks for you thoughts on this. Best regards!

EDIT: The code is pretty straight forward:

```
// static values
public static class DesignDefaultValues
{
    static DesignDefaultValues()
    {
        LabelColGridLength = new GridLength(22d);
    }

    public static GridLength LabelColGridLength { get; private set; }
}


// XAML USAGE    
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeClass}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeClass}">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{x:Static local:DesignDefaultValue.LabelColGridLength }" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> ...
```

Comment: I wish you would have added some code along with your problem.

Comment: I think in this case fits the *attached* dependency property, but to be exactly sure, you have to show the example code.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev: There's no need for APs here, I believe. The control is my own. It's about how CustomControls get instantiated.

Comment: Can somebody confirm that FrameworkElementFactory holds the static double by value and does not load it again, when the next instance of the control is created?

Comment: Where is the style created? Window.Resources?

Comment: Yes, I think so. If you really want to implement for static property `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, you can do this by using the `Singleton` pattern. Let me know if you need a example.

Comment: @devhedgehog: It is loaded and created via a central resourcedictionary into the Application resources.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev: Thank you for you kind answer. The value is not databound. INotifyPropertyChanged will do nothing on that. Your are right, I could databind, but I don't need a solution. I just want to understand what's going on there.

Comment: So basically you create the control few times but the style is always staying the same instance inside the Application.Resources. There you go why you always get the same value of LabelColGridLength. On its look up way to find the style, the same style will be return for different instances of your control. It makes sense because the application.resources will be created only once.

Comment: @devhedgehog: good guess, but this is a CustomControl Template not a style. While a style is only applying values to a target, a Template builds a visual tree via the FrameworkElementFactories (mostly). It is not a style that gets created at some point in time and doesn't change afterwards.

Comment: By the way the value doesn't get updated when we are changing our themes. Internally we are clearing all reasources from the application  and reload them. Still the FrameworkElementFactory for this control appears to stay in memory holding the old value... -.-

Comment: Nope, when style defined and initialized wpf system creates sort of a shallow instance of the targettype. That means if the style is created in application.resources the shallow instance of the targettype is also there. That futhermore means no matter how many controls you create, their style, template, data templates, ... etc instances will be always pulled from application.resources. Wpf system doesnt use FrameworkElementFactory for appling the default templates. It reads their xaml stream manually. And yes, FrameworkElementFactory in your case holds that one instance.

Comment: Maybe you need a look to [`x:Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev good point. x:Shared is by default set to true. If the OP sets it to false I guess it should work :) :)

Comment: @devhedgehog: Thank you for that answer. It is really interesting and I believe you understood the problem. FrameworkElementFactory is indeed deprecated. What I don't understand is: if default templates are applied via loading xaml manually why isn't the updated value not loaded from the static class? It is NOT a resource. Do you know anything about where/why/how the value is cached?

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev: Yup, I found that interesting too. BUT... :)
It is not a resource I am referencing. x:Shared is only for contents of resourcedictionaries, but I am referencing a property from a static class. Still, a really good point! Thank you guys so far. It is great talking to you and understanding more about this. :)

Comment: @Gope setting x:shared in resourcedictionary definition has no effect. you need to set it like this: <Style x:Key="myStyle" x:shared="false" TargetType="{x:Type SomeControl}">.. There are scopes in wpf system. System scope, application scope, window scope. Whenever you initialize something, no matter if through code behind or through resourcedictionary key, it stays in its scope. FrameworkElementFactory supports factory pattern and give you an new instance of certain control but the control' styles, templates are staying in their scopes and are not initialized via FrameworkElementFactory.

Comment: @devhedgehog: Maybe I wasn't clear: as far as I know x:Shared can only be applied to objects (resources) within a resourcedictionary, but I wasn't using an resource, just a plain field. That's why I think x:Shared will not help... ah *slap* 
Sorry... of course. It should get applied to the style setting the template and then... I thought you wanted to apply it to the field. I will try that. Thanks so far

Comment: ............upload your project please hehehehe

Comment: ;) --- one really needs 15 chars for a comment...