# How to reference static class field from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I have the following class that is referenced by my XAML:

```
public static class SearchVariables
{
    public static DataGridCellInfo current_cell_match;
    public static string current_cell_property;

    public static void setCurrentCell(Object dgi, DataGridColumn dgc, string property_name)
    {
        current_cell_property = property_name;
        if (property_name == null)
        {
            current_cell_match = new DataGridCellInfo();
        }
        else
        {
            current_cell_match = new DataGridCellInfo(dgi, dgc);
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is set up a MultiBinding Converter that uses current_cell_match when it changes. I have the following but it throws an error could use some help to resolve this.

```
<Setter Property="helpers:SearchBehaviours.IsTextMatchFocused">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedSearchValueConverter}" FallbackValue="False">
            <Binding Path="(helpers:SearchBehaviours.IsFindPopupOpen)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            <Binding Path="(helpers:SearchVariables.current_cell_match)" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

[EDIT]

Should have mentioned that this class sits with a bunch of attached properties and behaviors, so it is on the UI side of things. One of these behaviors sets current_cell_match.

Comment: Use [x:Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135(v=vs.110).aspx) to access static fields from XAML.

Comment: What is the error it throws?

Comment: @RohitVats I have tried Casper's example below without luck, do you have an example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make a binding to a static property in a static class try the following:

```
<Binding Source="{x:Static helpers:SearchVariables.current_cell_match}" />
```

But this will not update in the view when the values are changing. To update the view you need to implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged. But this can be pretty tricky when using static properties. Instead I would suggest to implement the singleton pattern, and make your static properties "normal" properties. The differences between a static class and the singleton pattern are not that big. So this might be the way for you to go.

Here is an example. Xaml:

```
<Binding Source="{x:Static local:MyClass.Instance}" Path="MyInt" />
```

Code:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Random random;

    private int m_MyInt;
    public int MyInt
    {
        get
        {
            return m_MyInt;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( m_MyInt == value )
            {
               return;
            }

            m_MyInt = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private static MyClass m_Instance;
    public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if ( m_Instance == null )
            {
                m_Instance = new MyClass();
            }

            return m_Instance;
         }
    }

    private MyClass()
    {
        random = new Random();
        m_MyInt = random.Next( 0, 100 );

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed( object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e )
    {
        MyInt = random.Next( 0, 100 );
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "" )
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
        {
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Happy coding :-)

Comment: 'helpers:SearchVariables' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name

Comment: Cannot find the member "SearchVariables" on the target type.

Comment: I apologize the mistake @Hank. I have updated my answer to a correct static binding.

Comment: Thankyou the error has cleared up. That's funny I just created a question on your extended answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883306/how-to-create-this-shared-class-member-or-property you can place your answer in there also if you like. So I have multiple behavior classes, can they can all access this singleton class? Actually I think I get it, it's like an internal class, but then if I place all my behavior classes into a parent class couldn't I accomplish the same as above?

Comment: Yes, all your behavior classes can access the singleton instance and bind to its properties (if needed).

Comment: I am not sure, I understand the "all my behavior classes into a parent class"-part. You can have a parent class where all of your behavior classes acts as properties of your parent class. But I would not recommend this. 
Don't know if this answers your sub question :-)

Comment: Thanks for your time, because I'm not sure exactly what I'm after I'm having issues with terminology and describing what I'm after. I close this one, have a play and ask another question if I need to

Answer (score 1):

Static members can be problematic in terms of PropertyChanged. Please take a look at the question I asked a short time ago:

[x:Static value in Control does not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824046/xstatic-value-in-control-does-not-update)

Mabe  x:Shared will help you.

Comment: Error when using x:Shared... The tag 'Shared' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'